# Why does the Weyl group permute the weights?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, $T$ a subtorus of $G$, and $\mathfrak g$ the Lie algebra of $G$.  Then there exist characters $\chi_1, ...  , \chi_t$ of $T$, and subspaces $V_i = V_{\chi_i}$ of $\mathfrak g$, such that $\mathfrak g$ is the direct sum of the $V_i$, and $\textrm{Ad }x(v) = \chi_i(x)v$ for any $x \in T, v \in V_i$.  The characters $\chi_i$, excluding the trivial character if it occurs, are called the *weights* of $T$.

Fix a weight $\chi$, and let $g \in N_G(T)$.  Then $g$ induces a character $\chi'$ of $T$ given by $\chi'(x) = \chi(gxg^{-1})$.  I am trying to understand why $\chi'$ is also a weight of $T$.  In other words, given that there exists a $0 \neq v \in \mathfrak g$ such that $\textrm{Ad }x(v) = \chi(x)v$ for all $x \in T$, why is it the case that there exists a $0 \neq w \in \mathfrak g$ such that $\textrm{Ad }x(w) = \chi(gxg^{-1})w$ for all $x \in T$?

Comment: If $v \in V_\chi$ then try to show that $gv \in V_{\chi'}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\textrm{Ad } g(v)$?  I had tried this, but it doesn't appear to work.  You are saying that if $x \cdot v = \chi(x)v$ for all $x \in T$, then $x \cdot (g \cdot v) = \chi(gxg^{-1})v$ for all $x \in T$?

Comment: It does work. $x\cdot (g \cdot v) = g \cdot (g^{-1}xg) \cdot v = g \cdot \chi(g^{-1}xg) v = \chi(g^{-1}xg)g\cdot v$, valid for $v$ in the $\chi$-weight space of any $G$-module.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I was so tired last night when I asked this question