# How does the weyl group act on weights\roots

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, characters, weyl-group

Let the Weyl group be:
$$W=N(T)/T$$
where $T$ is the maximal torus of some lie group $G$ and $N(T)$ is the normalizer of $T$.
I saw that in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770925/why-does-the-weyl-group-permute-the-weights) that the Weyl group acts on weights by:
$$(w.\chi)(t)=\chi(wtw^{-1})$$
but as far as I know weights (are characters and thus) are class functions. This will mean $w.\chi = \chi$.

Am I missing something? I looked in other sources but none write the action of the Weyl group explicitly.

Comment: Yes: the $\chi$ in that question are characters of $T$, not of $W$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Oh thanks :) I felt like I was missing something simple. Could you post it as an answer so I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters $\chi$ are characters of $T$, not of $W$, so they're not class functions for $W$ - in fact they're not even defined on elements of $W$.